# How can a c++ exe locate a c# dll?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, clr

I am trying to run a c++ application that uses a c# dll.
I created a clr wrapper class so that the c++ exe can load the c# dll.
When I run  the exe from the same directory where the c# dll is located, the application runs fine.

But, what I would like to do is to put all my application's dlls in another directory.
so my question is:

How can I put the c# dll in a different directory from where my c++ app is located, and enable the exe to load that dll?

I believe there is an option to use a configuration file, but I do not understand how exactly this is done.

Can anyone explain the way it can be achieved?

Comment: This strongly appeals to a programmer's mind, we all like to categorize things, but it is no different if this were a native DLL.  The OS absolutely hates having to find a them in an unusual place.  The CLR does likewise.  DLL Hell is a gritty problem you'd never want to create intentionally.  This otherwise works the *exact* same way it does if the EXE were created in C#, the CLR still goes looking for an appname.exe.config file.  It does not matter that appname.exe was created in C++.  And likewise, they must be located in a sub-dir to make probing work.

Answer (score 1):

If the dll's directory is a subdirectory of the executable, you may use [`<probing>` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) of your app.config:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="dll_subdirectory_name"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In my case the c# dll is not located in a subdirectory, but in an upper directory. is there a way to configure that?

Comment: This is trickier. You may utilize [`<codeBase>` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/codebase-element) but the assembly should be signed.

Comment: I have tried using <codeBase> element unsuccessfully. I believe the reason is the "href" element required. My dll is located in my localhost under c:\.  and the example for using this element refers to: "URL where the runtime can find the specified version of the assembly.". so if I want the app to use dll located under my c:\ ?

Comment: ..how can I refer to that in my app.config?